# unable to change root scope model value in Angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am trying to change my root scope model value upon ng dialog close but the value is remaining as it is.  I am expecting `$rootScope.isNgDiagClosed` to be 'true' when I click 'Show More' button and click close button in ng Dialog. But `$rootScope.isNgDiagClosed` always remaining `false`. Can any one help me to fix this? please find [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Z39jz0q6q2RXPPhiX8Z?p=preview)

The following is my code to change the value upon ng dialog close :

```
app.controller('InsideCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {

        $scope.closeTopList = function () { 
        $scope.isTopCarrierListClosed = true;
        ngDialog.close();   

    };

    });
```

Comment: Where is the `$rootScope.isNgDiagClosed`?

Comment: typo error, but fixed the issue. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

need to modify the model in the controller at root scope level.     The following fixed the problem. Updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Z39jz0q6q2RXPPhiX8Z?p=preview) with fix.

```
app.controller('InsideCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, ngDialog) {

            $scope.closeTopList = function () { 
            $rootScope.isNgDiagClosed = true;
            ngDialog.close();   

        };

    });
```